# Reducer in NgRx takes old state after dispatching second action in a row

Tags: angular, ngrx, ngrx-store, ngrx-effects

Every employee has many skills and it can be accessed with employee.skills, and I made logic to add, delete and update them.

Everything works perfectly except this situation:
For instance let's say I add a skill. Ok skill gets added, component re-renders and skill is shown in the list. After that I update some other skill. This other skill gets updated, but the previously added skill gets deleted from the list. In Redux DevTools extension I see that update skill action took old state (the state before newly added skill) and just updated the other skill. **BUT after I refresh the page**, everything seems ok: New Skill is there and the other skill is updated.
This happens no matter which action in which order is dispatched.

First action:
[Add skill](https://i.stack.imgur.com/03EnA.png)

Second action: [Update some other skill](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qL9Qv.png)

Employee model:

```
export class Employee {
  id?: number;
  firstName: string;
  lastName: string;
  skills?: Skill[];

}
```

Comment: Can you add the `Employee` interface to your Question ?

Comment: In your `UPDATE_SKILL_SUCCESS` reducer function, can you replace the first line with `let newState = state['skills']` and try.

Comment: THAT ACTUALLY SOLVED IT! Thank you so much!

Comment: Great, I'll add it as a solution. Feel free to accept it.

Comment: In order to accept my solution as the correct solution, you would need to click on the Grey Tick mark present to the left of my answer below. After you will click it, it will turn green in color.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem seems to be in the `UPDATE_SKILL_SUCCESS` reducer function.

The `ADD_SKILL_SUCCESS` function is adding the new skill to the `skill` property present in the `EmployeeState`. You are not adding it to the `skill` present within `Employee` object.
Now, while updating the skill, you are getting the `newState` from the `skills` property of the `Employee` model (which does not have the newly added skill).

So in order to get it working for you, you need to tweak your `UPDATE_SKILL_SUCCESS` reducer function a little bit.
Replace the first line with
`let newState = state['skills'];` and it should work for you.